# MySql can insert the values

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an custom CMS and trying to insert the value

The result query works well but the result2 query starts giving an error

Even i tried adding that in same query but that still gives me the same error

```
            $sname=addslashes($_POST['sname']);               
            $descr=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['descr']);
            $eve_format=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eve_format']);
            $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $pbm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pbmstat']);
             $group=$_POST['group'];
            $feat_img=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feat_img']);
        $query="INSERT INTO events (descr,name,eve_format,prize1,prize2,eve_sname) VALUES ('".$descr."','".$name."','".$eve_format."','".$prize1."','".$prize2."','".$sname."')";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $qry2="INSERT INTO events (group) VALUES ('".$group."')";
        $result2=mysql_query($qry2) or die(mysql_error());
```

The error i am getting is

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group) VALUES ('1')' at line 1
```

I am unable to figure whats wrong over there

I don't think i have any syntax error over there

Comment: "I don't think i have any syntax error over there" - I find the SQL parser is always correct.

Comment: Can you help me where i am wrong over there @MitchWheat

Comment: why do you have separate insertions? whats up with that? shouldn't that be that group is included in the first query?

Comment: Just do as  `$qry2="INSERT INTO events (`group`) VALUES ('".$group."')"; you just need to specify `` symbol before and after group column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hint is already on the MYSQL ERROR highlighted.

```
right syntax to use near 'group)
```

Because `group` is a mysql reserved word.

You need to wrap it with backticks

```
`group`
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
>
> <sub>Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860140/3859027</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`group` is MySQL reserved keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either add a back tick against it `group`

OR

add DB Name before it

e.g.

`TABLE_NAME.group`

But, the best way **if possible** is to rename `group` to something that is not a MySQL reserved keyword.